# Rails 5 Select tag inserts "[ ]", %5B %5D in html search string

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, select, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to use a rails select form field to populate multiple fields in a search form. But the search string returned has erroneous [] brackets inserted.

https://test-selects.c9users.io/cars?utf8=✓&car_year%5Bcar_year%5D=2016&commit=Search+Cars

proper format should be:

https://test-selects.c9users.io/cars?
utf8=✓&car_year=2016&commit=Search+Cars

```html
<%= form_tag(cars_path, :method => "get", id:"search-form") do %>
  <%= select(:car_year, :car_year, ["2017", "2016", "2015"]) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search Cars", class: "search-but" %>
<% end %>
```

The code above is a simplified version using just a few sample years but it yields the same results as when I was returning an array from my model that held the data for the select field.

select(:car_year, :car_year,...

I've tried every combination of :car, params[car_year] etc. and the brackets alway show up.

The same code works fine in a post method. When I provide a properly formatted search URL the search provides the expected results, I can also get expected results when I use a text_field_tag so I know my controller and model are working properly.

Help for this rookie would be greatly appreciated.

Code show above was simplified but produces the same results.

Comment: try  URI.decode to decode url

Comment: URI.unescape(encoded_uri)